# How to convert my cypress code into generic Type script parameterized function

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress

As I am new to this UI automation/cypress world, need help to setting up the assertion on javascript object return by **cypress-ag-grid** package

My code is reading ag-grid data

```
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
cy.log(data)
})
```

Which is printing below object in console

```
[
{ id: 1, name: "tata", saftyRating: "50" },
{ id: 2, name: "maruti", saftyRating: "50" },
{ id: 3, name: "ford", saftyRating: "45" }
]
```

My cypress code is:

```
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
  data.forEach(({ saftyRating }) => {
    cy.wrap(+saftyRating).should('be.gt', 50);
  })
});
```

This is working fine till the moment I try make it generic parameterized typescript function which is as below:

```
columnValueAssertion(colname:string, asserttype:string,value:number){
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
      data.forEach(({ colname }) => {
        cy.wrap(+colname).should(asserttype, value);
      })
    });
}
```

And calling it as:

```
columnValueAssertion('saftyRating',"be.eq",50)
```

It is throwing assert error:

```
-assert NaN is not equal to **50**
```

And when I am replacing the `colname` by `saftyRating` it is working fine
Not sure how convert this to parameterized function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're always trying to destructure a property named `colname` from the data, not a property with the name stored in `colname`. This results in `undefined`, and `+undefined` is `NaN`. You could use indexed access instead:

```js
data.forEach((datum) => {
    cy.wrap(+datum[colname]).should(asserttype, value);
});
```

or you could rename the column with a computed property:

```js
data.forEach(({ [colname]: column }) => {
    cy.wrap(+column).should(asserttype, value);
});
```